# How to hide website information on Wappalyzer

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.8, owasp

I have a website written in Laravel 5.8 and when I search my website info on **wappalyzer.com** website, I can see all the entire information of my website there.

And this is not good due to OWASP security test. So I'm looking for a way to hide the information of my website on **wappalyzer.com** .

So here is the official [suggestion](https://www.wappalyzer.com/articles/how-to-hide-technologies-from-wappalyzer) for Laravel based websites:

> **Hide Laravel from Wappalyzer**
>
> The Laravel PHP framework can also be identified by inspecting a
> websites' cookies. It's possible to change the default cookie name to
> prevent this.
>
> [laravel.com/docs/session](https://laravel.com/docs/session)

But I don't get what it means by changing default cookie names!

So if you know, please help me out with this and I would really appreciate that...

Comment: I'm curious what aspect of the OWASP security test makes the fact that wappalyzer.com knows you use Laravel not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `config/session.php`

The cookie created here:

`'cookie' => env( 'SESSION_COOKIE', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session' ),`

So, you just need to change the APP_NAME in .env

And dont forget the `php artisan optimize` to clear the cache

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses the env's `APP_NAME` in the cookie name. By default the `APP_NAME` is "Laravel" so your cookie name will be "laravel_session". You can go ahead and change your app name in your `.env` file. You can also change the `session` part if you edit your `config/session.php` file or by adding `SESSION_COOKIE` to your env.